# Select and compare two columns from different tables to find matched records

Tags: mysql

I'm just learning PHP and MySQL and I have two tables in the same database : FirstYear , SecondYear that have a structure like this :

```
StudentId |Math | Physics       StudentId1 | Math1 | physics1
Joe         10     14              Alan       12       17
Alan        13     17              Smith      11       13
Smith       9      9               Joe        10       15
```

Is it possible to write a query that select and compare the two columns StudentId , StudentId1 to find matched records and if for example Joe=Joe after that compare records of math with math1 and physics with physics1 that are in the same row as matched records of StudentId with StudentId1 ;the idea of this query is to study the improvement of same student from first year to the second one ,Thanks .

Comment: These tables are all wrong. There must be must be three tables - students, subjects, marks. in the marks table there must be a student id, subject id, year and mark

Comment: you can use JOIN

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible but you have to complete **SQL fundamental course**.

In this situation you have to know about **JOIN**. Such as, **Inner Join, Left Join, Right Join, Full Join** etc. Also, compare with unique id, not name. Because, name always duplicate. It is not good practice.  So, Know about **primary key** and **foreign key**. 
However,

**Query-**

SELECT * FROM FirstYear INNER JOIN SecondYear ON FirstYear.StudentId = SecondYear.StudentId1 WHERE FirstYear.id = 1

Something like that, alternatively, you can try to another logic.